# Node.js C++ add-on trying to execute javascript code with `require` function

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, require, v8

I'm maintaining a Node.js add-on in C++.

I need to call a SQL parser (a very non-standard variant of SQL, actually) inside an asynchronously called C++ function, but unfortunately (for me) that parser has been implemented in Javascript using some Node.js libraries (the function `require` is being used); this is an example of the kind of javascript code I need to execute:

```
require("./util/SqlParser")("SELECT 1 FROM DUAL").getSyntaxTree()
```

I've tried writing something like this:

```
v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::GetCurrent();
v8::Local<v8::Context> context = isolate->GetCurrentContext();
v8::TryCatch trycatch;
v8::Local<v8::String> source = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate
    ,
    "require(\"./util/SqlParser\")(\"SELECT 1 FROM DUAL\").getSyntaxTree()"
    ,
    v8::NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked()
    ;
v8::Local<v8::Script> script = v8::Script::Compile(context, source).ToLocalChecked();
v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> result = script->Run(context);
if( result.IsEmpty() )
{
    v8::Local<v8::Value> exc = trycatch.Exception();
    if( !exc.IsEmpty() )
    {
        auto msg = exc->ToString();
        if( !msg.IsEmpty() )
            throw std::string( *v8::String::Utf8Value(msg) );
    }
    throw "unknown error in called js function";
}
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work.  The net outcome is the error message `"ReferenceError: require is not defined"`: apparently, my context doesn't know anything about Node.js.

I tried to wrap the above expression in a js function `parseSqlText`, but this function is equally unknown to the script executor (I get the error message `"ReferenceError: parseSqlText is not defined"`).

My question is: is there any way to get around this?

Any help would be very appreciated. I would be very glad to avoid reimplementing that parser in C++... which at present seems the only viable way to do what I need.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_callbacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First, v8 is **not** Node.js, Node.js is built on top of v8.
- v8 is a javascript engine
- Thus Node.js libraries are not carried with v8 by it-self


      The **N-API** is the answer to question. Although, normally it is used to write native C++ plugins for Node.js. The github thread belwo has some examples. Additionally, the node.js docs for N-API have also been linked.

       [Github Thread](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/23265#issuecomment-429076703)

       [Node N-API Docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/n-api.html#n_api_n_api)

EDIT: It would seem the work has been done already, here in this [repository](https://github.com/rubys/node-embed). The writer made it so it appears to abstract all the prep work of v8 and be one line for you.

```
#include "node_embed.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    node_context *context = nodeSetup(argc, argv);

    if (context) {
        nodeExecuteString(context, "let foo = 1", "__init__");
        nodeExecuteString(context, "foo = 2", "__init__");
        nodeExecuteString(context, "console.log(foo)", "__init__");

        return nodeTeardown(context);
    } else {
       return 12;
    }
}
```

The above is from the repository and will allow you to run that snippet of code.

Comment: It's pretty clear to me that v8 is not Node, thanks. It's also clear that N-API is not "the answer" to my question, but just another library to study and understand before I can only hope to find an answer...  Could you please at least point out which part of this library allows me to execute some javascript code in an asynchronously called function? thanks

Comment: Edited the answer to hopefully accomplish what you have asked.

Comment: Thank you! Actually it seems that my Node.js is too old (version 8.something) to support the function `node::NewContext`, which seems the key to the solution of my problem :-(  Thanks anyway, maybe I'll try to postpone my task until we upgrade to Node 10...

Comment: @MauroMarchesi, how did you solve this. I am getting exactly same error.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you go find an SQL parser that is *already written* in C++.  I found one *immediately* in a ten-second search on `github.com`.

In my opinion, there is zero technical justification for bringing the JavaScript language into this scenario, just to be able to "parse SQL."  You will not have to "write from scratch" anything at all.  It will just be an object – pluck it "off the shelf," instantiate an instance of it, and use it.

Comment: The point is that I cannot use an existing SQL parser. I said "SQL" just to give the idea of how complex it would be to rewrite it, but actually it's the parser of a proprietary SQL-like language.. no existing parser outside my company, unfortunately.